# Obj-C: Callback is not executing

Tags: objective-c, callback, nslog

Any idea why the callback is not executing? `panoServie` is initialized and everything. I put the NSLog messages there, and nothing happens.

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D) randomLatitudeLongitude
{
    CountryBBVal auBB = [[GGData SharedInstance] boundingBoxForCountry:Australia];
    //NSLog(@"BB: %f, %f, %f, %f", auBB.NELat, auBB.NELng, auBB.SWLat, auBB.SWLng);
    double ranLongitude = [self randomDoubleBetween: auBB.NELng and: auBB.SWLng]; // Boundix Box
    double ranLatitude = [self randomDoubleBetween: auBB.NELat and: auBB.SWLat];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D ranLatLng = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(ranLatitude, ranLongitude);
    //NSLog(@"ranLatLng: [%f] [%f]", ranLatitude, ranLongitude);

    __block GMSPanorama *panPhoto = nil;
    [self.panoService requestPanoramaNearCoordinate:ranLatLng callback:^(GMSPanorama *panorama, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"panorama: %@ error: %@", panorama, error);

            panPhoto = panorama;
    }];

    if (!panPhoto) return [self randomLatitudeLongitude];


    return ranLatLng;
}
```

Comment: Is your callback block asynchronous? If so, its started in background and the code execution jumps immediately after it to the `if (!panPhoto)` where `panPhoto` is most probably still `nil`. It causes the `return [self randomLatitudeLongitude]` ending the method

Comment: @Lukas, I don´t know - the callback is part of the Google Maps SDK. should I try putting the if and return statement inside the block?

Comment: Update: It IS asynchronous, I checked the doc´s. Can I just put the return statements inside the block?

Comment: You definitely should. Callbacks are most often asynchronous, which means they don't block code execution. But whole the method structure does not make sense. You shouldn't have getter method `randomLatitudeLongitude` with async execution inside. also, line `if (!panPhoto) return [self randomLatitudeLongitude];` calls itself which will lead to the infinite recursion

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178278/why-is-this-cllocationcoordinate2d-variable-unassignable/18178308#18178308) to another question, see if it helps

Comment: @Lucas. it is supposed to recursively call itself until it get´s a panPhoto that is non-nil. Cause if I give it random coordinates, and a photo does not exist at that location it should just return nil. So I wan´t to contiunue on giving random values until it find a valid location.

Comment: @Tom well, I think the recursion is not a good idea in this cause. It can take a looong time (infinite in extreme cases). You should at least have some threshold of max recursive calls

Comment: @Lukas: true enough, it might cause a Stack Overflow

Comment: @Tom I`ve summed all of my comments to the answer. Its my opinion, you may or may not take it in account ;-) Decide yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `- requestPanoramaNearCoordinate:callback:` is asynchronous request. Its started and the code execution is not blocked. So the `if (!panPhoto) return [self randomLatitudeLongitude];` is called immediately with `panPhoto` most probably being still `nil`, so the `return` statement is performed.
2. Overall method idea does not seem right to me.

   - You should not have async block called in the getter-like method (which should return the result immediately). If you really want some method like this, you should define your own callback block for this method being called in the `requestPanoramaNearCoordinate` callback.
   - Calling `return [self randomLatitudeLongitude]` itself in the method is also not a good idea. It can cause infinite recursion. There should be at least some max recursion calls threshold